# Rxjs , issue while concating data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Behaviour Subject in my application. and i subscribed that Behaviour Subject as below.

```
 tableData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

i am using next() method to set data from some other function as below

```
for (let item of data) {
    let objArr = [];
    // some code here like for loop (i am processing 100k records)

    objArr.push(object);
    if (objArr.length == 20) {
        this.tableData.next(objArr);
        objArr = [];
    } 
}
```

I have subscribed this BehaviourSubject as below. but i am unable to show all records from DB.

```
this.data = [];
this.utilServ.tableData.subscribe((data) => {
    if (data.length !== 0) {
        for (let item of data) {
            this.data.push(item);
        }
    }
});
this.utilServ.tableData.next([]);
```

It is only showing last records.

How to combine/merge/concat the data from Behaviour Subject?

Comment: Why do you call `this.utilServ.tableData.next([]);`? To clear the `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: yes to clear the BehaviorSubject because my DB response has 1 lakh of records.

Comment: What do you mean It is only showing last records? I don't really get question

Comment: if i keep on appending records in for loop the size of Behavior Subject may incresae

Comment: What is `1 lakh of records`? If you have too much data to keep in memory, how do you think you can concat them?

Comment: then remove this line and everything is okay `objArr = [];`

Comment: i will try and let both of you know

Comment: working fine but processing time not decreased, plesae let me know this also

Comment: I'm confused here. You say you want to merge/concat data but you also say that you have huge amount of data to process. Even if you somehow merge the data, how are you going to present it in the view? I think you are contradicting yourself here. Maybe you should revise your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use next of `behaviorSubject` you can use next on  accumulated array.

**One way is to write like this**

```
const newValue = this.tableData.value.concat(objArr);
this.tableData.next(newValue);
```

Comment: do you have any idea to enhance for loop functionality, while processing huge number of records, please let me know or share any link

Comment: In my opinion you can use data paging, which means to first fetch part of the data not the total amount of it. I mean like instead of querying for thousand, first query for hundred and make paging possible. So take hundred on first page. So that makes your for loop more efficient. If this helps you I can direct you to it

Comment: Thanks @Koreli, it is helpfull, My PM also said same, first show only 100 records, after that when user click on the pagination buttons process the remaining.i am Using ng zorro antd table here.  please let me know if you have any suggestions